# Updating Module in Oracle Sql Developer Data Modeler with sql script

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, data-modeling, oracle-sql-data-modeler

I have an update script I want to apply to my model in oracle data modeler. Is there a way to do this because I haven't been able to find one?

I am using Oracle SQL Developer Data Modeler Version 4.2.0 Build 932.

Thanks,

-Ian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File > Import

DDL Script

[image]

Then you can merge in your changes as desired.

[image]